# What's the difference between using a stateless functional component versus calling a method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand stateless components and what the difference is between these examples:

```
class App {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderAFunction('hello')}
      </div>
    );
  }
  renderAFunction(text) {
    return (
      <p>{text}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

and this:

```
class App {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <RenderAFunction text='hello'/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const RenderAFunction = ({text}) => (
    <p>{text}</p>
);
```

Or if there is any difference at all?

Comment: For now React doesn't support lifecycle method with [Stateless Functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html), probably it will be fixed in a future. I'm not sure about other differences (i'm talking about your second example)

Comment: Also, one of the main points of React is to separate components. If `RenderAFunction` is actually a component, then it should be treated like one, and not wedged into a higher-level component. It gives you more flexibility, makes functionality easier to find, etc.

Comment: You might want to compile the JSX away and look at the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functionally, there is absolutely no difference. Both end up rendering a paragraph element, but there are  other aspects to consider. There are three points to make (in my opinion) when examining both methods:

- **Reusability**: You have to understand to separate components when you need to. If `renderAFunction` is just meant to generate some JSX based on, for example, an API request, then it's fine being in a method. But if you want to reuse it somewhere else, then separate it into it's own component. A huge part of React is component reusability and getting rid of code duplication. Separating the method into it's own component would be imperative to accomplish this.
- **Purpose**: There are reason to use **stateless** function components and reasons not to. The whole point of stateless functional components is to not have state and be presentational. If you need to do something that involves the React lifecycle or internal state, keep it as a method, or new class depending on if you want it reusable.
- **Performance**: Using a stateless functional component *would be less efficient*. This is because *it's a component*, not just some JSX returned from a method. As of right now, the React team plans on making some optimizations for stateless functional components because they do not contain state and are merely presentational, but this probably won't happen until after React Fiber is done and thus your stateless functional component *has no optimizations versus a regular full-fledged class component*. That makes it incredibly inefficient versus a method returning some JSX, especially if it's just used once in another component.

A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself, do I need it anywhere else? If not, then keep it in a method. If you don't need it anywhere else, separating the JSX into a separate component would have worse performance and wouldn't follow React's core principles.

If you are going to need it somewhere else, then separate the component so you follow React's concept of reusability.

Comment: About "_Using a stateless functional component would be less efficient. This is because it's a component, not just some JSX returned from a method._". Aren't they just a simple function that react interprets as a component? I mean, you're defining an anonymous function that returns JSX, really.

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan Yes, that's a good concern to raise. It's true that stateless components are just functions that "return some JSX". The whole "functional component would be less efficient" means that with a function component, you'd have to do `<MyComponent />` involving another `React.createElement` call, but with some returned JSX from a component method, they would just be treated as children of some parent element, which `<MyComponent />` would also do.

Answer (score 2):

Your `App's` `render` function  will be translated into following JS code for your first example:

```
render() {
   return React.createElement(
     'div',
     null,
     this.renderAFunction('hello')
   );
 }
```

And the following one for the second one:

```
render() {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    React.createElement(RenderAFunction, { text: 'hello' })
  );
}
```

While they both looks almost the same, there is one significant difference: **laziness**. `React` will execute `RenderAFunction` body only in case it gonna be mounted to the DOM hierarchy.

It is insignificant is your case, but imaging following example:

```
const LazyApp = () => {
  const heavy = <div><HeavyStuff /></div>
  // ...
  return <div>done it</div>
}

const HardWorkingApp = () => {
  const heavy = <div>{HeavyStuff()}</div>
  // ...
  return <div>done it</div>
}

const HeavyStuff = () => {
  // ... do heavy rendering here
}
```

Lazy app will not perform any heavy stuff at all. Maybe it is not very clear from that synthetic example why one would do anything like that at all. But there are real-world examples out there, when something conceptually similar (creating `Components` without rendering them) is happening.

Comment: The usual place I use functions is to make my ternaries simpler, but ternaries are already lazy. In that case `{x ? foo() : null}` is just as lazy as `{x ? <Foo/> : null}`. Good point though, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, both will serve the same purpose. But the real advantage of creating a component is its reusability.

If you have to render that particular piece of jsx just for this component. Then, there is no need to create a separate component.